# Seeking a novel in which the hero recognizes the spice smell of oncoming enemies

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember a scene from what was probably an otherwise un-memorable novel, which I would like to locate again.  This was read at least fifteen years ago in English, but I don't remember much else.

The main character is with a group of people (maybe military) with enemies somewhere else in the region.  Suddenly, for reasons that are not initially explained to the reader, he tells everyone in the group to hide in the trees.  Soon after, while they group is in hiding, the enemies show up and pass by without noticing the protagonist's party.  It turns out that the enemies are cultists with certain food restrictions, and he smelled the spices they cook with, alerting him to their imminent approach.

Comment: So was this set on Earth? Were the enemies human or alien?

Comment: @Danny3414 I believe that it was set on another planet, but all the individuals involved were human.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This reminded me of a scene in a military SF novel which I haven't reread in a long time: [***Dorsai***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25316), by **Gordon R. Dickson**. I had to check my copy, just now, to confirm the details. For instance, I couldn't remember whether the young officer had ordered his men to climb *up into the trees* after a certain aroma was detected. Turns out he did!  So I believe this is the same story you were remembering.

"Dorsai" is the name of an entire culture in the setting of "the Childe Cycle" (a name Dickson eventually started using for the entire series of which this book is just one portion). The Dorsai pride themselves on being far and away the best-trained soldiers the human race has ever produced. Fortunately, they have *no interest* in conquering all the other human cultures on other planets, and setting themselves up as the aristocracy of a new empire; instead, they are content to support their local economy by hiring out as high-priced mercenaries who are often assigned to command local troops in wars taking place on other worlds.

The main character of *Dorsai* is Donal Graeme, a young Dorsai officer who, in this sequence, is out in the field with his first command of actual soldiers after he's completed his training to be an elite military officer. (And in the course of this novel, he turns out to be something remarkable as a military leader, even by Dorsai standards.)

Specifically, Donal Graeme is now on the world of Harmony (full of feuding religious factions), on a mercenary contract to support one side of a local war. His client is "the First Dissident Church." His current rank is "Force-Leader" and he has a Force of 150 infantrymen following his orders. (So his authority seems to be similar to that of a "Captain" serving as "company commander" in the modern U.S. Army, for instance.)

At one point, Donal asks his ranking Senior Groupman (seems to mean: "the most senior NCO in the company," in our terms) for the name of a man with a keen sense of smell. A soldier named Lee is mentioned. Donal sends for him. Then Donal states that just the three of them (himself, Senior Groupman Morphy, and Lee) are going to move forward a few kilometers, very quietly. Once they're up on a ridge, we have this scene in which Donal *silently* gives Lee an order:

> Donal tapped Lee on the shoulder and when the other turned his face
> toward him in the gloom, Donal touched his own nose, pointed down into
> the valley and made sniffing motions. Lee turned his face back to the
> valley and lay in that position for several minutes, apparently doing
> nothing at all. However, at the end of that time, he turned toward
> Donal again, and nodded. Donal motioned them all back down the slope.

After they get back to camp, Donal asks Lee what he smelled, and Lee says there was a faint scent of something sour that he couldn't identify from past experience. Donal asks if Lee has ever served on the world of Harmony before, and Lee says no. Donal doesn't press the matter any further, nor does he explain *why* they made this bit of olfactory reconnaissance in the first place.

However! Later on, Donal blows a whistle to awaken Lee.

> "What—?" mumbled a sleepy voice from half a dozen meters’ distance. A
> hammock heaved and disgorged the bony figure of the ex-miner. "What
> the hell ... sir?"
>
> Donal strode up to him and with both hands swung him about so that he
> faced toward the enemy territory from which the dawn breeze was coming.
> "Smell!" he ordered.
>
> Lee blinked, scrubbed his nose with one knotty fist, and stifled a
> yawn. He took a couple of deep breaths filling his lungs, his nostrils
> spread—and suddenly he snapped into complete awakedness.
>
> "Same thing, sir," he said, turning to Donal. "Stronger."
>
> "All right!" Donal wheeled about on the sentry. "Take a signal to
> Senior Groupmen, First and Second Groups. Get their men into trees,
> high up in trees, and get themselves up, too."
>
> "Trees, sir?"
>
> "Get going! I want every man in this Force a dozen meters off the
> ground in ten minutes—with their weapons!" The sentry turned to make
> off. "If you’ve got time after making that signal, try to get through
> to Command HQ with it. If you see you can’t, climb a tree yourself.
> Got that?"

So he gets his 150 men up into the trees, and then they wait until they see enemy troops coming along, hoping to catch this military camp completely off guard. Which would have occurred, if not for Donal. The attackers do kill some of the men in other Forces, but Donal's command opens fire from above and pretty well annihilates the attackers before they realize the shots are not being fired from ground level.

Later, Donal is explaining to a young woman how he deduced that a sneak attack was going to occur at approximately that time and place, led by elite troops of the United Orthodox Church.

> "But you saw through this!" she snapped. “What’s your secret? A
> pipeline to the Orthodox camp?"
>
> "Surely it was obvious from the situation; a command exposed, a
> commandant foolishly making a love-tryst in a battleground, that
> something like the attack was inevitable. I simply asked myself what
> kind of troops would be used and how they might be detected. Orthodox
> troops eat nothing but native herbs, cooked in the native fashion. The
> odor of their cooking permeates their clothing. Any veteran of a
> Harmony campaign would be able to recognize their presence the same
> way."

Comment: That woman, I think I recall, was a priestesses who had been breed to fall in love with the most puissant man in the Galaxy; there was just a great deal of confusion about who that was.

Comment: That's pretty much correct. She was called "the Select of Kultis." Kultis was her homeworld; "Select" apparently meant her genes had been very carefully selected to make her something remarkable. (I'm not sure about the "Priestess" part per se.) Only at the end of the story was it revealed that the leaders of her culture had meant her to be programmed to be powerfully attracted to the most outstanding male with whom she came in contact --  intended to be the evil political strategist who was the Big Bad of the book. The meteoric rise of Donal Graeme threw a monkey wrench into that plan.